# Quarkus dependency injection not discriminating on uriInfo being injectable or not

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, quarkus

I am not sure this is a bug, I think that this is more me not knowing how to properly use Dependency Injection within Quarkus.

I have the following setup in Kotlin with Quarkus 2.16.3:

```kotlin
interface Resolver {
    fun getInfo(): String
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Default
@Priority(1)
class ResolverNoRequest(): Resolver {
    override fun getInfo(): String {
        return "myInfo"
    }
}

@RequestScoped
@Alternative
@Priority(2)
class ResolverWithRequest(val uriInfo: UriInfo) : Resolver {
    override fun getInfo(): String {
        val hostname = uriInfo.baseUri.host
        return "myInfo with $hostname"
    }
}
```

I have another class that get injected like this

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class Consumer(val resolver: Resolver){
    
    fun process(){
        println(resolver.getInfo())
    }
}
```

What I would like to have is:

- In the context of a request: the "ResolverWithRequest" is injected (if started with a batch)
- When there is no request: the "ResolverNoRequest" is injected (if started from a rest endpoint)

I have tweaked (actually alot) with the annotations, and changed the signature of Consumer to have `Instance<Resolver>`.
But I did not manage to get them by discriminating on whether the `uriInfo` is there or not.
In fact when the `ResolverWithRequest` is proposed (when there is no request) it crashes because there is no `uriInfo` ( `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No RESTEasy Reactive request in progress`).
I would have expected the Consumer not to get injected with the ResolverWithRequest in case of no request.

The only (very ugly) solution I found on my own is to have Instance<Resolver> with a try catch block.

I am persuaded that Quarkus is an elegant framework, and I think I am missing something.

It would be awesome if someone could help on this :)

Here is the little extract I have made so that you can reproduce on your end without friction:
https://github.com/olivierbeltrandocintoo/quarkus_kotlin_mini_injection_issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done this easily, because dependencies are resolved based on their type and qualifiers, and nothing else. Therefore, you will always get your `ResolverWithRequest`, because it is an enabled alternative (and has highest priority).

However, you can create your own facade that will dispatch to the correct `Resolver` based on whatever criteria you need.

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
@Alternative
@Priority(10)
class DispatchingResolver(
        val global: ResolverNoRequest,
        val perRequest: ResolverWithRequest
): Resolver {
    override fun getInfo(): String {
        if (isRequestActive()) {
            return perRequest.getInfo()
        } else {
            return global.getInfo()
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I might be making some lousy mistakes, as I don't write Kotlin daily, but I guess you know what I mean.)

This works correctly, because both `ResolverNoRequest` and `ResolverWithRequest` are *normal-scoped* beans and hence the objects injected into `DispatchingResolver`'s constructor are *client proxies*. A client proxy will only obtain the actual bean instance upon method invocation.

Now, how do I find out if a request is active? There's probably more than one way, but here's one. CDI's `BeanManager` lets you obtain a context object for given scope (`BeanManager.getContext()`), except that throws an exception. ArC has a method will just return a `null` context if the context is not active: `ArcContainer.getActiveContext()`. So you can do this:

```kotlin
fun isRequestActive() = Arc.container().getActiveContext(RequestScoped.class) != null
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the help !!
Unfortunatly the isRequestActive is true :D
I have updated the code to use the DispatchingResolver, but still the test fails because the RequestsScoped returns a non null object. also it has isValid set to true and everything :D
Too bad I cannot send screenshots, I am going to push a newer version of the example with your suggestions :)

Comment: Here is the updated example: https://github.com/olivierbeltrandocintoo/quarkus_kotlin_mini_injection_issues/commit/4ca836cc1f305e5a93d0cd61025ff74538812d13 :)

Comment: One of the tests in your modified example passes as expected. The other fails because the `isRequestActive` function is imprecise (my bad, should have realized this). In Quarkus, the request context is active in a lot of other scenarios, not just during actual HTTP requests. For RESTEasy Reactive, you can replace the `isRequestActive` function by something like this: `fun isRequestActive() = org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.CurrentRequestManager.get() != null`.

Comment: Hi @ladicek :) 
Many many tnanks ! I have tried your suggestion and it works really well ! To be completely honest also, I have Implemented that class that gets injected both Resolvers, that you suggested. Thanks a ton for the help and time :) So answer accepted ! I cannot "+1" with this new account though, I will do it with my personal one ;) Cheers